# Discord.js : A part of the code does not work, but there is no error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I start the bot there comes the Ready message but wehen one of somebody send for example a link into a channel nothing happens. Ther comes no error. I had to reduce the code because of the stackoverflow limit. There were three other parts but they worked. Only these two parts doesnt work.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const TOKEN = '';
const PREFIX = '!';

//ready
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

//welcome
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log('User joind');
});

//commands
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
        }

        //delete links
        else if (message.content.includes('https://')) {
            console.log('Link!!!');
        }

});


client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: What is the expected result? If your message doesn't start with the prefix, your bot won't do anything because `if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return`. As for the `guildMemberAdd` check your settings: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the message does not have the required prefix, thus the the function just returns.